# Run Jar file with more than one argument

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea

I am building an optimization into a JPEG-Encoder written in Java. To do my benchmark i want to extract the orginal code and the optimized code into separated jars. Each jar has to take two arguments. The first on for the file name and the secound for the repeat of the compression of the jpeg.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filepath = args[0];
    try {
        int times = Integer.getInteger(args[1]);
        runBenchmark(filepath, times);
    } catch(IOException | NumberFormatException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Your arguments are Wrong! Use the follow order!");
        System.out.println("1. Argument must be the filename of the image.");
        System.out.println("2. Argument must be a number to repeat the compression.");
    }
}
```

This is my main, witch handle my args. I cant run the arguments on IntellJ . Even if I compile it the a jar, i cant pass my arg2.
[image]

I passed two arguments via configuration in intellj and i get a NullPointerException. So i tried to figure out if my java can take two arguments. I wrote a simple main in vim and compiled ran it with two args and worked. I repeated this in a new Project in intellj.[image]
This is working. But why?

Comment: The stack trace is illegible and so is the code. Can you insert both into the question as text, please?

Comment: I found the misstake. I wrote it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if the parameter is a int or not.
Use Integer.parseInt() and a try-catch block to inform the user if a failure happen.

```
int times = 0;
try {
  times = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("failure with a parameter");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed the method to Integer.parseInt(string) and now it works. It was the Integer.getInt() it . I thought i had now 2. arg because I get the NullPointerException.
Now it work with this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String filepath = args[0];
        int times = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        runBenchmark(filepath, times);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println("2. Arg must be an number");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Your arguments are Wrong! Use the follow order!");
        System.out.println("1. Argument must be the filename of the image.");
        System.out.println("2. Argument must be a number to repeat the compression.");
    }
}
```